# What's the solution of a differential equation, when the "limit" is 0

Tags: calculus, limits

Sorry if the questions sounds horrible to all the mathematicians' ears out there, but my math level is limited, and I just try to get a better intuitive idea of what happens in that case.

I "understand" the concept of differential. It's the change of a function over a certain value (for example the change of speed over time): dV / dt and dt tends to 0. Now my question is, what happens when dt = 0, is it a valid case (can this happens? can it be said), and if yes, is it somehow connected to the Dirac delta function. Finally a friend of mine told me this has somehow a connection with something called the "limit theorem" in differential calculus? I found some info about a "limit theorem" but that doesn't seem to be connected at all to this.

Your help is greatly appreciated, and sorry again if I am not using the right terminology. Please correct me, I am here to learn.

Thank you -

Comment: If you mean $\Delta y=y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)$ to be the change in $y$ afforded by the change $\Delta x$ in the input variable $x$, then $\Delta y/\Delta x$ approaches the derivative $y'(x)$ as $\Delta x\to0$ in the limit. Of course you cannot directly plug in $\Delta x=0$, but sometimes you can simplify the expression $\Delta y/\Delta x$ and *then* plug in $\Delta x=0$. (**Look up *limit* and *derivative***.) Studying the Dirac delta function isn't be the best idea if you are not already knowledgeable of derivatives and limits and calculus in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the curve $y = x^2$, and the point $(2,4)$ on that curve. What's the slope of that curve at that point?

Well, if I have two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, the slope of the line connecting them is $\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. But of course we only have one point here. Let's move along the curve very slightly: let's say that we move from $x = 2$ to $x = 2+\delta$ (where $\delta$ is something really small), so that $y (= x^2)$ is now $(2+\delta)^2$, i.e. $4 + 4\delta + \delta^2$. (Draw yourself a picture of these two points on the curve, and the line through these points.)

The slope between the points $(2,4)$ and $(2+\delta, 4+4\delta+\delta^2)$ is $\dfrac{(4+4\delta+\delta^2) - 4}{(2+\delta) - 2}$, which you can easily simplify to $4+\delta$. So what's the slope *at* $(2,4)$? Well, it's what happens when $\delta$ tends to 0 (this is formally called a *limit*) - that is, we'll get $4$. But can we just set $\delta = 0$ right from the start? No - because then we get a 'slope' of $\dfrac{4-4}{2-2}$, which obviously doesn't make any sense.

Now do this again for two points $(x, x^2)$ and $((x+\delta), (x+\delta)^2)$. The slope function you get at the end is called the *derivative* of $y = x^2$, and often written $dy/dx$, but these $d$ things are just formal symbols, and you shouldn't think of them as numbers. It's just code for what I wrote above.

Does this help?

Comment: And no, this doesn't have much to do with the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks a lot. That's a good start for me. I was asking about the Dirac delta function because I read a book talking about differential solid angle (in relation to light), in which they were saying that light rays in the real world were never collimated so the concept of differential solid angle always applied. However it was possible to "mathematically" consider collimated rays, and that you can still make this case "mathematically" valid by using the dirac delta function. So I was trying to make a relation between these two things (e.g. can you use this function when limit=0?).